# Linking data from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

We have an Access database and UI that's running reliably.  The accdb file is stored on a network drive visible to my SQL Server.  I'd like to link that data to my SQL Server.  CRUD that happens in the Access DB (via the Access UI), I would like to show up in the SQL database.  In this situation, the Access DB is the master, and SQL Server is the slave.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You are better off migrating your tables to be actual SQL Server tables, then use the Link Table Manager in your Access DB to pull those in. Going the other way is a little off.

Comment: How quickly does it need to show up in the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You could link the SQL Server tables via *ODBC* to your Access application.

Then, in this, create queries and/or code that append/update the data from the Access tables to the SQL Server tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is usually done the other way around; Access FE and SQL Server BE, but yeah, you can do it the way you described.

You should probably bone up on some basic things first.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2484/import-data-from-microsoft-access-to-sql-server/

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-SQL-Server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e

Now, to push, or pull, the data, create a Stored Procedure and suck in whatever you need from Access.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspCopyTable
AS

INSERT INTO
dbo.mytable (myfield)

SELECT
myfield
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'c:\mypath\mydb.mdb';'admin';'mypwd', mytable)
GO

fire it off by something like this

dim cn as adodb.connection
set cn = new adodb.connection
cn.open "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
"Data Source=myServerName;" & _
"Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI"
cn.execute "dbo.uspCopyTable"
```

OR, use VBA to push the data from Access into Excel.

```
Make new table:
Dim strsql As string
strSql = "SELECT * Into YourNewAccessTableName FROM ExistingSqlTableName"
Currentdb.execute(strSql)
Insert into existing Access table (assume fieldnames are the same:

Dim strsql As string
strSql = "INSERT Into YourAccessTableName SELECT * FROM ExistingSqlTableName"
Currentdb.execute(strSql)
```